# How to have midbar be at proper height

Tags: equations, fractions

Take these examples:

```
$$5|\frac{a}{b}$$
```

```
$$\frac{f_r}{a+c}|x$$
```

```
$$\left[\frac{1}{2}|\lim_{x\to{}x_0}f\left(x^2\right):\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}|\iiint_V \mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw\right]$$
```

I want those mid bars to be at a correct height. What do I have to do ?

Comment: Try `\mid` instead of |

Comment: Do you mean \left and \right?

Comment: put \big, \Big, \bigg or \Bigg before the bar to increase it size. Alternatively use \left and \right to autoadjust to the content if you are enclosing something between two bars

Answer (score 1):

`\middle|` may help you, but it works within `\left` and `\right`, may be the below `MWE` suits for you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left.5\middle|\frac{a}{b}\right.
\]

\[
\left.\frac{f_r}{a+c}\middle|x\right.
\]

\[
\left[\frac{1}{2}\middle|\lim_{x\to{}x_0}f\left(x^2\right):\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}\middle|\iiint_V
\mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

PS: I've changed all `$$` to `\[...\]`, hence `$$` is a code for `PlainTeX`

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use \big,\Big,\bigg,\Bigg or their location--specific equivalents (e.g. \bigl,\bigm,\bigr), use \begin{equation} or [ instead of $$, and use upright d at the end of integrals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dif}{\,\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}


\[
\left[\frac{1}{2}\Bigm|\lim_{x\to{}x_0}f\left(x^2\right):\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}\Bigm|\iiint_V \mu(u,v,w) \dif u\dif v \dif w\right]
\]

\end{document}
```